# canvas draw circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wish to draw circle but when I fill() my arc all other shapes which are under "circle" and arent't fullfilled fill() with the same color as arc. Can anyone help me to solve it?

Comment: screenshot would be welcome =]

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... and `closePath()` after being done with the previous shapes

Answer (score 1):

Call `beginPath()` before starting to draw the circle.